# Is it safe to accept url from user to show in our website?

Tags: php, security, phishing

I wanna show users websites in their profiles but I don't know after I validate the user's input format to be the valid URL (https://userwebsite.com), is it safe to use that input in a tag (`<a href="https://userwebsite.com">`) to redirect other users to that website? if it's not safe is there any way to check the URL??

how facebook and others handle this situation like example below

https://www.facebook.com/pages/Restaurant-El-Reda-libanesische-und-iranische-Spezialit%C3%A4ten/169985763015422

Comment: Safe in what way? It's no different from them clicking on the link anywhere else. It can't hurt your website, or access their data in your site.

Comment: @Barmar yeah, I see, in my website, it is important for users to put their website to be seen by others so I wanna know how can I recognize malicious URLs in my website to reduce threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great question. There are many sites that provide the ability for users to enter URLs that are then provided as links. This has been bread and butter of forums for a long time.

The challenge is that we want to make sure that the URL is valid and doesn't encourage people to visit malicious sites. For the first part (is the URL valid) there are plenty of libraries out there that can check the URL for example [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) for python. (Sorry I don't know PHP well enough to provide the equivalent example).

The second part is a little more interesting and depends on your circumstances. If you are running a non commercial site then [Google Safe Browsing](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing) offers an API which I believe will allow you to filter out malicious links. If you are running a commercial site then there are alternatives for example [SophosLabs Intelix](https://sophos.com/intelix).

In summary I believe that it is safe to do what you are asking as long as:

1. You validate that the URL is valid
2. You put reasonable checks in place to prevent users posting links to malicious content
3. You provide appropriate disclaimers to cover you against the content on external sites

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely not.

Keep this in mind that accepting anything from user means danger, this is you that should handle the danger in a safe way.

You can get a URL from a user but it might be harmful for others ...

Comment: how facebook and others handle this situation like example below https://www.facebook.com/pages/Restaurant-El-Reda-libanesische-und-iranische-Spezialit%C3%A4ten/169985763015422

Comment: @nima good question. It is not 100% dangerous and it is not dangerous for you and your website but if you left a certain bug in your website it could be use for code injection and other goals. I said it could be harmful for other users !
Facebook and Instagram has the report option and they can take care of their platform with users reports ...